# Humhub: "failed to open stream: Too many open files" (Hosting: Strato.de)

Tags: php, hosting

**I have landed on a white screen after the login.**

On my log file `/humhub/protected/runtime/application.log` was the following error:

> 2015/07/03 11:56:12 [error] [php]
>   include(/protected/vendors/Zend/Search/Lucene/Exception.php): failed
>   to open stream: Too many open files
>   (/protected/extensions/EZendAutoloader/EZendAutoloader.php:34)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Instead of editing your own post you can answer your own question and accept it as an answer to avoid unanswered questions on the website ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was on my hosting configuration:** You have to go to the "Configuration->Website-Configurator->PHP-Version" and disable "PHP Boost". It will increase the process capacity on your server and will allow Humhub continue working.